# MySQL and Python (pyodbc): Procedure Entry Point OPENSSL_sk_new_reserve could not be located

Tags: python, mysql, openssl, python-3.7, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a remote (hosted on dreamhost) MySQL database from Windows 10.

I installed the latest version of the 32-bit MySQL ODBC driver (I am running 32-bit python) and run the following code:

```
connection_string = (
    r'DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver;'
    r'SERVER=https://mysql.mysite.com;'
    r'DATABASE=dbname;'
    r'UID=userid;'
    r'PWD=password;'
    r'charset=utf8mb4;'
    )

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

using the correct server, database name, userID, and password, obviously.

I can access it from the mysql workbench with this information and these credentials, but when I run the code above, I get this message:

```
The procedure entry point OPENSSL_sk_new_reserve could not be 
located in the dynamic link library c:\Program Files (x86)
MySQL\Connector ODBC 8.0\libssl-1_1.dll.
```

When I click ok on that, I get this message in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pasto\OneDrive\Documents\Python\work.py", line 129, in <module>
    print(get_mysql_data())
  File "C:\Users\pasto\OneDrive\Documents\Python\work.py", line 109, in get_mysql_data
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  127: The specified procedure could not be found. (MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver, C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\Connector ODBC 8.0\\myodbc8a.dll). (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

### Other things I have tried:

**Google**. All I've found is stuff about anaconda, which apparently also has this problem.

**Renaming the libssl_1-1.dll library**
Then the error code changes to

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded 
due to system error  126: The specified module could not be found. 
(MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver, C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\Connector ODBC 
8.0\\myodbc8a.dll). (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

**Installing** (via pip) **mysql-connector**, then tried

```
import mysql.connector
    
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="https://mysql.mysite.com",
      user="username",
      password="password"
    )
```

but that just gets me

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\
connector\network.py", line 600, in open_connection
errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL 
server on 'https://mysql.fairplainpc.com:3306' (11001 getaddrinfo failed)
```

I've been at this for hours and am this close to giving up and using the requests library to download a PHP page with the data I want and parse that instead, but I would really prefer to make this work.

Comment: Try running `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` and creating a System DSN, using the "Test" button to see if the connection is successful.

Comment: "Connection successful." It showed the table I was trying to connect to.

Comment: Hmm, okay. In your Python code are you really using a `SERVER=` parameter that begins with `https://`. That probably won't work. Try just using `SERVER=mysql.fairplainpc.com`

Comment: I tried ditching the https already. It didn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a bug report at [mysql.com](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91844) from someone else having a similar error.

Their workaround was to install a previous version of the MySQL ODBC driver. They installed the 5.3 driver (as of 7/21/20 can be found [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-odbc/) - select it from the dropdown).

I uninstalled 8, installed 5.3, and changed the driver line to

```
r'DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver;'
```

It worked instantly.

Comment: Aha, so it's a Windows 10 thing. I was testing with Windows 8.1. Thanks for posting the answer. However, does the driver name still say "8.0"?

Comment: I don't know if it's Windows 10 specific, but based on your comment, I suspect it is. And no, I meant to change the driver line to 5.3 but forgot. Whoops! I'll correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection_string with your data:

```
connection_string = (
'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};'
'SERVER=https://mysql.mysite.com;'
'DATABASE=dbname;'
'USER=userid;'
'PASSWORD=password;'
)
```

If you don’t run the mysql server by yourself, you may have to assign your ip address to your database user or add your ip to an exclusion.

For example Hostpoint (Switzerland):
[image]

Comment: I don't have the 3.51 driver installed.

Comment: @PythonPastor You can download it here: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).
Then you can look up your installed drivers under: ODBC data source (32-bit)

Comment: I already installed the 5.3 driver, and that worked.

Comment: @PythonPastor if it is installed, you can look it up at: ODBC Data Source (32-bit)
Under the tab "Drivers" you will find all installed drivers & their correct names.